# How to do range lookup and search in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I try to code in PySpark a function which can do combination search and lookup values within a range. The following is the detailed description.

I have two data sets. 
One data set, say `D1`, is basically a lookup table, as in below:

```
MinValue  MaxValue Value1 Value2
---------------------------------
1          1000      0.5     0.6
1001       2000      0.8     0.1
2001       4000      0.2     0.5
4001       9000      0.04    0.06
```

The other data set, say D2, is a table with millions of records,  for example:

```
ID      InterestsRate       Days       
----------------------------------
1       19.99               29
2       11.99               49
```

For each `ID`, I need to calculate the maximum return based on different credit limit with possible values of `500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000`.

The return is calculated as, for example,

> f(x) = InterestsRate * Days * Value1 * Value2.

`Value1` and `Value2` are determined by looking up a credit limit in `D1`. For example, if the credit limit is 3000, the looking up `D1`, 0.2 and 0.5 will be returned.

For each record in `D2`, I want to calculate the return on different credit limit and find out the credit limit and return which gives me the max return.

So far I have completed two functions:

I defined a lookup function as

```
def LookUp(value):
    filter_str = "MinValue <=" + str(value) + " and MaxValue >=" + str(value)
    return D1.filter(filter_str)
```

I also defined a search function as

```
def Search(rate, day):
    credit_limit = [500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000]
    max=0;
    cl=-1;
    for i in range(1: len(credit_limit)):
       v1 = lookup(credit_limit[i]).select("value1")
       v2 = lookup(credit_limit[i]).select("value2")
       tmp = rate*day*value1*value2
       if max < tmp: 
          max=tmp 
          cl=credit_limit[i]

    return (cl, max)
```

I will call the following transformation on D2:

```
res = D2.mapValues(lambda row: Search(row[1], row[2]))
```

With surprise, I run into errors and I googled that I cannot use data frame (`D1`) within a transformation on RDD (`D2`).

I also googled that the possible solution is to broadcast `D1`. However, I don't know how to make it work.

Would you please comment on how to implement this function in PySpark?

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your table, credit limits of 500 and 1000 will always return the same row in `D1`. Since your "return" (`tmp`) is not a function of the credit limit, these two will always return the same value for return. I have a potential solution for you, but it would be helpful if you provided the desired output for this example. (Also there's a bug in your `Search` function - `x` is not defined.)

Comment: Thank you for your recomments. The returned values are totally depends on the min value and max value. if I change them,credit limit 500 and 1000 may fall into different buckets. Am I clear?

Comment: OK but in this example, they fall into the same bucket- so the returns will be the same. What value would you pick in that case? The max credit limit?

Comment: Yes. if two credit limits give me the same return, the max credit limit will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using `spark` you should think in terms of `SQL` and table joins instead of looping over lists.

So the first thing I would do is to turn your credit limits list into a table, let's call it `D3`:

```python
credit_limit = [500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000]
D3 = spark.createDataFrame([[x] for x in credit_limit], ["CreditLimit"])
D3.show()
#+-----------+
#|CreditLimit|
#+-----------+
#|        500|
#|       1000|
#|       2000|
#|       3000|
#|       5000|
#+-----------+
```

Now, you can join this table to `D1` and `D2` to compute the return for each credit limit, and then pick the max return using `Window` function to rank each return. As you [stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506913/how-to-do-range-lookup-and-search-in-pyspark#comment90011801_51506913) we will pick the maximum credit limit if there is a tie.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(f.desc("Return"), f.desc("CreditLimit"))
D2.alias("D2").crossJoin(D3.alias("D3"))\
    .crossJoin(D1.alias("D1"))\
    .where("D3.CreditLimit BETWEEN D1.MinValue AND D1.MaxValue")\
    .withColumn("Return", f.expr("D2.InterestsRate*D2.Days*D1.Value1*D1.Value2"))\
    .withColumn("Rank", f.rank().over(w))\
    .where("Rank = 1")\
    .drop("Rank")\
    .show()
#+---+-------------+----+-----------+--------+--------+------+------+------------------+
#| ID|InterestsRate|Days|CreditLimit|MinValue|MaxValue|Value1|Value2|            Return|
#+---+-------------+----+-----------+--------+--------+------+------+------------------+
#|  1|        19.99|  29|       1000|       1|    1000|   0.5|   0.6|173.91299999999998|
#|  2|        11.99|  49|       1000|       1|    1000|   0.5|   0.6|           176.253|
#+---+-------------+----+-----------+--------+--------+------+------+------------------+
```

We're doing 2 Cartesian products here so this may not scale well, but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to pyspark.... so have to understand each line first. Thanks a million! I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: One more question: in my real case, the calculation is far more complicationed. Can I replace f.expr("D2.InterestsRate*D2.Days*D1.Value1*D1.Value2") with a function?

Comment: You can but of possible, you should try to write the computation as a sql expression because it will be faster. If thats not possible, you'll need a `udf`

Comment: One more question: what is the difference between partitionby and groupby?

Comment: Effectively it's the same thing. When you are using a window function, we refer to grouping as partitioning.